# center div in screen without fixing width and height

Tags: html, responsive-design, screen, center

I use bootstrap to have a responsive design and I want to center one div in the screen

I tested that :

```
style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;"
```

but the top left corner of the div is in the center, I don't want put negative values of margin to make him reponsive

how an I solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

To fix a div at the center use,

```
style="margin: 0 auto;"
```

It will align div at the center.